# Custom App Folder in Django 1.7

Tags: python, django

So I used to use the following to include my custom app directory (for organization sake) and it worked well until Django 1.6

Noticed that it's not working with Django 1.7 (python 2.7). Any suggestions in the right direction will be much appreciated.

The only error I get is the inability to find the app included in the settings.py

```
import os
import sys

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'apps’))
```

Comment: what is your directory structure and what do your import statements look like?

Comment: blog > blog > settings.py (The default created by Django 1.7) and the app folder is in the root of the project

Comment: here > /Users/Zeus/Documents/Dev/django/blog/blog/blog (thanks in advance) -- this the location of Settings.py I created a virtualenv called blog inside of the folder django (that why you see blog thrice)